# Make a masonry layout with fluid layout

Tags: html, css, jquery-masonry

I am using this awesome and the most popular library http://masonry.desandro.com/ to display a masonry grid of images.

Now, I want a fluid layout i.e. the column widths should change according to the parent container's width. Exactly how bootstrap's `.col-md-4` works. I did set the width to 33% (Since I want 3 columns) but then I lost responsiveness; while, setting it to a fixed width (say `300`), gave me too much gap between columns.

Doing something like:

```
    // set columnWidth a fraction of the container width
    columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
        return containerWidth / 3;
    }
```

didn't help either.

This is my current code: https://codepen.io/vedant1811/pen/OXzOyo

Comment: You can use  `col-md-4` with your `.box` class

Comment: `col-md-4` works when its a child of a `row`. I tried that but it didn't work

Comment: Check this fiddel.. i have use `col-md-4` and it's worked.[ https://jsfiddle.net/w7qfdhkr/

Comment: doesn't work. `col-md-4` is not behaving like your regular responsive bootstrap class. On reducing width it jumps from 3 columns to 1. Should goto 2 instead.